# First call every day on azure API app is slow

Tags: java, azure, spring-boot, azure-api-apps

I have Java Spring boot REST API application on Azure(API App). 
Every day first call take about 30s or more. After that first call response is faster. Always On Is set to ON in application settings. I'm using tomcat.

Did anyone have similar problems?

Comment: nope, not really. we deploy to azure also. are you using java-8 btw? may be lots of lambdas are bootstrapped for the first time...

Comment: Yes I'm using java-8. I tried to call some other api call every day and always get same response time for first call.

Comment: it *might* happen because all lambdas and methods references are compiled to `invokedynamic` that will call a bootstrap method internally, so the first calls are slow - we faced this with Rhino if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Can I do something to fix that?

Comment: IFF that is the cause of the problem - there is not really "a fix" for that, it's just how it works. As a work-around what we do, is we have a bot that is authorized and "pings" all the API's once, to make those lambdas and method references to be build. I may sound stupid, but I've just opened our logs and the time difference for certain API's is in the range of tens of seconds - those are pretty large API's though and mainly is Nashhorn affected

Comment: If this is true. Should the same happen when I start app on the server locally? Because locally I don't have this problem.

Comment: yes, that should also happen locally, it this case I guess the problem is elsewhere